# Cannot get "public_actions" permission to work on app administrator account

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

We are currently adding Facebook integration to our product. I have set up our product as an app in the developer portal and have added myself as an administrator of that app. I am logging in to Facebook using the OAuth functionality for devices i.e. I'm posting to the "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/device/login" endpoint.

We specifically want to be able to upload videos using our app. I am therefore requesting the "publish_actions" permissions. Everything seems to work i.e. Facebook provides a device authentication code and I am able to poll until the user has accepted the request to add our app and once that is done, I receive back an access token.

The problem I am having is when I attempt to initiate a video upload by posting to the "https://graph-video.facebook.com/v2…/1533641336884006/videos" endpoint, I receive the error 200: "Subject does not have permission to post videos on this target". I can't find any information about what could be causing this in the developer documentation.

I understand that once the app integration is completed, I need to obtain permission to use "publish_actions" to allow it to work with Facebook accounts that are not administrators of the app, however I am trying to upload a video to my Facebook account, which is the administrator of the app.

It is my understanding that as long as you are the app administrator, Facebook does not need to approve "publish_actions" and I should be able to upload a video to my page. Indeed I need to be able to do this in order to complete the integration.

Can you advise on what might be going wrong?

Many thanks,

Damien

Comment: Check whether your token actually contains that permission. (How to debug, see docs.)

Comment: Thanks for the info, I did debug my access token and it appears to have retrieved all of the appropriate permissions, so I'm not exactly sure why it is not working. However, I have managed to integrate the .Net Facebook SDK which allows me to upload a video using the access token generated by my custom code, so perhaps it was a problem with the specific call I was making to Facebook.